# XPS Viewer shows empty page

Tags: wpf, xps

Im trying to print multiple pages. That for im adding WPF Frameworkelements to fixedpages and fixdpages to a fixeddocuement. Heres my Code

```
PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
            FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
            fixedPage.Width = doc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
            fixedPage.Height = doc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
            for (int j = 0; j < pageCount; j++) {


                foreach(FrameworkElement c in pages[j])
                {
                    children.Remove(c);
                    fixedPage.Children.Add(c);


                }

            }
            ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
            doc.Pages.Add(pageContent);




        printDlg.PrintDocument(doc.DocumentPaginator, "My first document");
```

unfortunately the XPS Viewer shows an empty document to me, does anybode know why?

thank you!